# from google.cloud import datastore gives 'ImportError: cannot import name 'collections_abc''

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, chatbot, datastore

I am installing google cloud datastore to build a conversational chatbot, using the command

```
!pip install google-cloud-datastore
```

This gives me following error:

> google-cloud-bigquery 1.9.0 has requirement google-cloud-core<0.30dev,>=0.29.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 1.4.3 which is incompatible.
> goes on to installing google-cloud-core-1.4.3 google-cloud-datastore-1.15.3.

Execute further

```
from google.cloud import datastore
```

gives following error:

> /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py in ()
> 20 import warnings
> 21
> ---> 22 from six.moves import collections_abc
> 23 from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlencode
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'collections_abc'

Answer (score 0):

Package `google-cloud-bigquery=1.9.0` seems to be old, I have `google-cloud-bigquery=1.28.0`. You can try to update first your Cloud SDK components and then install `google-cloud-datastore` again.  You can update the components with:

```
gcloud components update
```

It is possible that you will be required to execute equivalent `apt-get update` command.

The second error with `collections_abc` seems to be a [compatibility issue](https://six.readthedocs.io/), python2 is being deprecated, please use Python3 (pip3). If the issue with `six` persists, try installing different version for instance; `pip3 install six==1.15.0` as recommended in [this github thread](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/issues/304).